# Grails and Spring Security: How do I get the authenticated user from within a controller?

Tags: grails

I recently moved from the JSecurity plugin to Spring Security. How do I get the authenticated user from within my controllers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using 0.5.1 and the following works for me:

```
class EventController {
  def authenticateService

  def list = { 
     def user = authenticateService.principal() 
     def username = user?.getUsername()
     .....
     .....
  } 
}
```

Comment: Great- thanks! Just a typo in your above code. It should be def username = user?.getUsername()

Comment: Please note there have been some changes with the new version of Spring Security. [See here for example code for Spring Security version 1.1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775053/grails-and-spring-security-how-do-i-get-the-authenticated-user-from-within-a-con/6270545#6270545)

Comment: also note that if you use service, then initialization should ne not in method body but in class.

Answer (score 15):

It's not currently documented, but in the plugin installation file, there are 3 methods that it adds to every controller so that you don't actually have to inject the authenticationService:

```
private void addControllerMethods(MetaClass mc) {
    mc.getAuthUserDomain = {
        def principal = SCH.context?.authentication?.principal
        if (principal != null && principal != 'anonymousUser') {
            return principal?.domainClass
        }

        return null
    }

    mc.getPrincipalInfo = {
        return SCH.context?.authentication?.principal
    }

    mc.isUserLogon = {
        def principal = SCH.context?.authentication?.principal
        return principal != null && principal != 'anonymousUser'
    }
}
```

This means that you can just call

```
principalInfo
```

To get the principal object.  It also has "isUserLogin" to see if the user is logged and "authUserDomain" to get the actual domain class instance (the Person/User) associated with the principal of the logged in user.

Comment: I spent an hour and a half banging my head against the keyboard trying to get Acegi plug to work with the File Upload pattern shown in http://www.packtpub.com/article/file-sharing-in-grails until I found this. Thanks!

Comment: Now the method getPrincipalInfo is called getAuthenticateduser, but thanks for the good tip!

Comment: @lucke84 Looks like you're right: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/controllerMetaClassMethods.html - all the methods seem to have changed names in modern versions of this plugin

Answer (score 13):

The following code is from the [Spring Security Core Plugin (Version: 1.1.2) - Reference Documentation - Section 6.2](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html)

grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService provides security utility functions. It is a regular Grails service, so you use dependency injection to inject it into a controller, service, taglib, and so on:

```
class SomeController {
    def springSecurityService
    def someAction = { 
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser 
        …
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, I think the way to do it is:

```
def user = getAuthenticatedUser()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get current User by this way also

```
 class AnyController {
  def springSecurityService
  def someAction = { 
    def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)

     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()){   
        println "Logged In"

    }
```