# Groovy session. How to find the user name

Tags: groovy, session-management

I am developing an application under Groovy using scafoldig.
We are using the Acegi plugin for security.
We have a class called ChangeManagement defined as follows (simplified version)

```
class ChangeManagement {
static constraints = {
    company(nullable:false)             
    lastModifiedByUser(nullable:false)      
}

Company company    
static belongsToCompany = [company:Company]

User lastModifiedByUser 
static belongsToUser = [lastModifiedByUser:User]
}
```

When I address the create method I will get a pull-down menu
with the label "Last Modified By" with all the users from the table Users,
which is the standard behaviour.

Instead of this I would like to have directly the user who is already logged in and
no pull down menu. I've already generate the create template and I can modify it.
I am assuming that I have to get the username from the session. 
If my assumption is true, how to get this username? and if I am wrong then from where can I get the username of the current user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775053/grails-and-spring-security-how-do-i-get-the-authenticated-user-from-within-a-con/775901#775901) for details on how to get the current username.

I'd also suggest looking into [Grails Filters](http://www.grails.org/Filters) for one way to easily stuff the user into the model after all controller calls and make it available in the view.  I use this on my app to put the name of the logged in user in the upper right hand corner of the screen.