# How to get id of the current user logged in grails?

Tags: grails

I want to display the info about the user logged in like his details etc given during sign up ...how to do it ?? As iam new to grails plz help! iam using Spring security plugin

Comment: What do you think about using the search field above? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775053) for further information.

Answer (score 14):

Well you can use the springSecurityService to get some user information in a controller:

```
    class MyController {
      def springSecurityService

      def myAction() {
        def principal = springSecurityService.principal
        String username = principal.username
        ...
      }
     }
```

Or in a gsp

```
    <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" />
```

It is a pretty general question.

Comment: I know this is an old post but... I found it and it lead me to google and find this: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib

Answer (score 11):

Define (in a controller, or service where you need user id):

```
SpringSecurityService springSecurityService
```

and try:

```
springSecurityService.currentUser.id //loads user from db, and returns its id
```

or:

```
springSecurityService.principal.id //if you need just id
```

Comment: Fully qualified class name is `grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService`

Answer (score 1):

add this @the top of your service or controller class

```
def securityService
```

this returns the cuureent user id.

```
securityService.currentUser.id
```