# How to display CAS authentication username in grails application

Tags: authentication, grails, cas

I have an application in grails that uses the CAS authentication. I have managed to successfully authenticate thru CAS and view my application, however I want the username that has been entered in the CAS to display in my grails application. How can I achieve this? Is there a way to pass username? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming use used Spring Security method to do the CAS integration, you might check this other post: [Grails and Spring Security: How do I get the authenticated user from within a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775053/grails-and-spring-security-how-do-i-get-the-authenticated-user-from-within-a-co)